# unindent does not match any outer intendation level

Tags: python

al intentar correr el codigo me da el error "unindent does not match any outer intendation level" no entiendo en que falla el codigo :(
es para un trabajo de la uni, entiendo los fundamentos y todo pero no logro entender en que esta fallando mi codigo
el codigo es:

```py
ingreso: print("Ingreso: ")
born: print("Año de nacimiento: ")
Hijos: print("Numero de hijos: ")
BANCO: print("Años de pertenencia al banco: ")
Estado: print("Estado civil (""S"": soltero, ""C"", casado): ")
Vivienda: print("En que lugar vives? (""U"": Urbano, ""R"": Rural): ")

if (BANCO > 10 and Hijos > 2):
        print("APROBADO")
    if (BANCO < 10 and Hijos < 2) :
        print("RECHAZADO")

if (Estado == C or c and Hijos > 3 and born ==> 1976 or born ==< 1966)
    print("APROBADO")
        if (Estado == S or s and Hijos < 3 and born ==< 1976 or born ==> 1966)
            print("RECHAZADO")

if (ingreso > 2500000 and Estado == S or s and Vivienda == U or u)
    print("APROBADO")
        if (ingreso < 2500000 and Estado == C or c and Vivienda == R or r)
           print("RECHAZADO")

if (ingreso > 3500000 and BANCO > 5)
    print("APROBADO")
        if(ingreso < 3500000 and BANCO < 5)
            print("RECHAZADO")

if (Vivienda == R or r and Estado == C or c and Hijos < 2)
    print("APROBADO")
    (Vivienda == U or u and Estado == s or S and Hijos > 2)
        print("RECHAZADO")
```

Comment: puedes poner el código aquí? una imagen no es precisamente bien recibida por la comunidad

Comment: Bienvenido Ignacio c: Podrías poner el código en forma de texto por favor? Así es más facil ayudarte y no tenemos que transcribir tu código a partir de la imagen. Ponte en nuestros zapatos y piensa ¿Seria fácil pasar imagen a código para ayudar a alguien?

Comment: Puedes darle formato al código seleccionandolo todo y presionando las llaves que están arriba de la caja de texto donde escribes la pregunta.

Comment: Pues tienes un error de indentación en alguna parte. Es lo único que puedo especular sin ver el código. Revisa lo que tienes, porque seguramente es alguna cosa sencilla de resolver. Saludos

Comment: Tienes bastantes cosas que arreglar en el código, por ejemplo: `BANCO` no puede ser menor o mayor a algo (no es un número). Un montón de `if` sin los dos puntos al final, `Estado == C` debería ser `Estado == 'C'` (Esto te pasa en generál con todas las letras), al final te falta un `if`... Si consigues arreglar el problema de indentación te irán saliendo estos. Te recomiendo que comentes todos los párrafos menos el primero y vayas poco a poco arreglándolo.

Comment: Por otro lado, puesto que parece que lo que quieres es que el usuario introduzca datos, lo tendrás que poner con inputs: `hijos = int(input("Numero de hijos: "))` y transformarlos a `integer` con `int()`, ya que los `inputs` son cadenas de texto.

Comment: Hola Ignacio! Te recomiendo re pasar los fundamentos, como algunos compañeros han señalizado tienes errores que podrían considerarse muy básicos. Este curso te enseña python desde 0, a mi me ayudo cuando no tenia idea de nada. [Curso Python desde 0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2FCfQj-9ig&list=PLU8oAlHdN5BlvPxziopYZRd55pdqFwkeS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nota:**
Esta respuesta tiene como objetivo no solo corregir el error que nos cuentas, si no también enseñarte cosas de Python y evitarte futuros problemas.
En la respuesta doy por hecho muchas cosas que podrían ser erradas, por lo que puede que no solucione tus problemas. Además, en lo personal siento que esta respuesta no será bien recibida por la comunidad debido a lo dicho en la oración anterior y estar un poco fuera de topico.

---

Vamos a arreglar tu código paso a paso:

## 1- Solucionar errores de sintaxis:

Analizando tu código he encontrado estos fallos de sintaxis:

1- Tu código tiene varios errores de identación. En Python, la cantidad de espacios que pongas a la izquierda (identación) es importante, pues le indica a Python donde empieza y termina cada cosa.

2- Usas esto "==<" como menor o igual y esto "==>" como mayor o igual.
En Python, el operador correcto sería "<=" (para menor o igual) y ">=" (para mayor o igual).

3- Cada condicional (if, elif, else) tiene que terminar en ":". Muchos de tus condicionales carecen de dicho caracter.

4- Te falta un if abajo de todo.

5- No pones entre comillas la cadenas. Esto de ponerlas entre comillas es para decirle a Python que estás hablando de una cadena y no de una variable.

6- Para saber si una variable vale una cosa u otra tienes que usar el operador [in](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/in-and-not-in-operators-in-python#:%7E:text=Python%20%E2%80%9Cin%E2%80%9D%20operator,%2C%20list%2C%20or%20tuple%20etc.&text=When%20the%20specified%20value%20is,found%2C%20we%20get%20a%20False%20.) y usar una [tupla](https://entrenamiento-python-basico.readthedocs.io/es/latest/leccion3/tipo_tuplas.html) (poner cada valor entre parentesis y separarlos por comas).

El código revisado resulta en:

```
ingreso: print("Ingreso: ")
born: print("Año de nacimiento: ")
Hijos: print("Numero de hijos: ")
BANCO: print("Años de pertenencia al banco: ")
Estado: print("Estado civil (""S"": soltero, ""C"", casado): ")
Vivienda: print("En que lugar vives? (""U"": Urbano, ""R"": Rural): ")
    
if (BANCO > 10 and Hijos > 2):
    print("APROBADO")
    if (BANCO < 10 and Hijos < 2) :
        print("RECHAZADO")

# Notese el uso de las comillas y el operador in
if (Estado in ('C', 'c') and Hijos > 3 and born >= 1976 or born <= 1966):
    print("APROBADO")
    if (Estado in ('S', 's') and Hijos < 3 and born <= 1976 or born >= 1966):
        print("RECHAZADO")

if (ingreso > 2500000 and Estado in ('S', 's') and Vivienda in ('U','u')):
    print("APROBADO")
    if (ingreso < 2500000 and Estado in ('C', 'c') and Vivienda in ('R', 'r')):
       print("RECHAZADO")

if (ingreso > 3500000 and BANCO > 5):
    print("APROBADO")
    if(ingreso < 3500000 and BANCO < 5):
        print("RECHAZADO")

if (Vivienda in ('R', 'r') and Estado in ('C', 'c') and Hijos < 2):
    print("APROBADO")
    if(Vivienda in ('U','u') and Estado in ('S', 's') and Hijos > 2):
        print("RECHAZADO")
```

## 2- Ingreso de datos del usuario

Supongo que lo que deseas es que el usuario pueda ingresar una serie de datos a través de un input. La forma correcta de lograr esto es con el comando [input](https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/python/lecciones/python-entrada-teclado.html) que acepta como primer argumento el texto a mostrar y permite ingresar datos al usuario.
Además, para guardar valores en variables, se usa el "=", no el ":".

Teniendo esto en cuenta, las primeras 6 lineas de tu código pueden ser cambiadas por:

```
ingreso = input("Ingreso: ")
born = input("Año de nacimiento: ")
Hijos = input("Numero de hijos: ")
BANCO = input("Años de pertenencia al banco: ")
Estado = input("Estado civil (""S"": soltero, ""C"", casado): ")
Vivienda = input("En que lugar vives? (""U"": Urbano, ""R"": Rural): ")
```

Pero Python no es adivino, no tiene forma de saber si el dato que esperas que el usuario ingrese sea un numero o no. Por lo que un input siempre devuelve lo que escribió el usuario en forma de cadena. Algo que podemos hacer al respecto es asumir que el usuario escribira un numero. Por lo tanto así usar la función int para convertir la cadena en un numero.

Entonces asumiendo esto los inputs te quedarían así:

```
ingreso = int(input("Ingreso: "))
born = int(input("Año de nacimiento: "))
Hijos = int(input("Numero de hijos: "))
BANCO = int(input("Años de pertenencia al banco: "))
Estado = input("Estado civil (""S"": soltero, ""C"", casado): ")
Vivienda = input("En que lugar vives? (""U"": Urbano, ""R"": Rural): ")
```

Si, por ejemplo, el usuario ingresa un año de nacimiento NO numerico (ej: abc), se producira un error en el programa.